# libtorch and pytorch cannot be installed simultaneously?

Tags: python, linux, pytorch, libtorch

I am learning to develop with PyTorch as well as LibTorch. I have the following line in my `~/.bashrc` for dynamic linking of libtorch libraries:

```sh
# libtorch linking path
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/.dev_libraries/libtorch/lib/
```

However, when this path is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, importing `torch` in Python reports segmentation fault:

```sh
user@host:~$ $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
bash: /home/user/packages/embree-2.16.0.x86_64.linux/lib:/home/user/packages/embree-2.16.0.x86_64.linux/lib::/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:/home/user/.dev_libraries/libtorch-cpu/libtorch/lib/: No such file or directory
user@host:~$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
user@host:~$
```

As soon as I remove that path from the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `torch` can be correctly imported in Python.

I am guessing the cause is that some shared libraries of PyTorch having the same names as the ones in LibTorch. Does this mean PyTorch and LibTorch cannot be installed simultaneously, or is my environment setting incorrect? I'd prefer not to reset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` every time I switch between the two.

---

System specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04 + CUDA 11.1 + python 3.8.10 + GCC 9.3.0
- pytorch 1.9.0+cu111
- libtorch is downloaded from here: https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-latest.zip

Comment: Google: "libtorch" can mean {the libs only}. `pip3 install torch` *is* providing the libs. Example: `dist-packages/torch/lib/{ libc10_cuda.so, libc10.so, libcaffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.so, libcaffe2_module_test_dynamic.so, libcaffe2_nvrtc.so,
libcaffe2_observers.so, libcudart-80664282.so.10.2, libgomp-a34b3233.so.1, libnvrtc-08c4863f.so.10.2,
libnvrtc-builtins.so, libnvToolsExt-3965bdd0.so.1, libshm.so, libtorch_cpu.so, libtorch_cuda.so,
libtorch_global_deps.so, libtorch_python.so, libtorch.so }`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem too.
You can type

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

to see the version of torch, and use the same version of libtorch, that would solve the problem probably.